# Finding position of last digit in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to format some number plates - I need to find the last digit in a string and add a space after it, e.g.

```
T4MAX  = T4 MAX
T53TES = T53 TES
```

I'm assuming I'll have to use preg_replace - I've tried the below to find the position in the string of the last digit, but it returns an empty array.

```
preg_match('/(0-9])/', $plate, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy:

```
$str = 'T4MAX';

$str_with_space = preg_replace('~\d(?=\D*$)~', '$0 ', $str);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/Mqqqsh

Regex explanation:

`~\d(?=\D*$)~` expression means - any digit `\d` followed by anything that is not a digit `\D` by the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly, if I wanted to switch it around, so add a space before the first number, how would I do that?

Comment: @Ryan Pilbeam: `(?<=^\D*)\d` - here is a regex for that

Comment: I've tried doing this:
`var_dump(preg_replace('~(?<=^\D*)\d~', ' $0', $plate));`
But assuming I'm doing something wrong, I get this error: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 8

Comment: @Ryan Pilbeam: right. Lookbehind assertions should have been of a fixed length.  Let me think

Comment: @Ryan Pilbeam: here: `preg_replace('~(^\D*)(\d)~', '$1 $2', $str)` PS: don't forget to check my answer as correct ;-)

Comment: @Ryan Pilbeam: you haven't - there is a green checkmark icon right below the answer rating arrows